# What does hg copy do?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge

We recently did a `hg copy` of a directory in our repository. We thought it
does something like `cp -a` and `hg add` and maybe flag somehow that
this file has been copied from another file inside the repo (so `hg
annotate` shows the original committer). But it now seems that `hg
copy` does more or different stuff than that. I couldn't really find
much on how exactly copy works. So:

- What exactly does `hg copy` do and what special treatment does this
  cause in the future?
- If it turns out to do "the wrong thing(tm)" for our case, how do I
  unflag the file as beeing a copy of another file?

(This question was asked on the Mercurial mailinglist, you may want to [follow the original thread](http://mercurial.markmail.org/thread/yotjumnywxes5q4j) too.)

Comment: You can also read [Copying files](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/hgbook/1.7/mercurial-in-daily-use.html#chap:daily.copy) in the [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/hgbook/1.7/) book.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> - What exactly does hg copy do and what special treatment does this
>     cause in the future?

It adds new files and marks them as copies of the old files. Because they are copies, a change made in the original file will be merged into copy. Time flows from left to right:

```
(init) --- (edit a.txt) ---- (a.txt edit is copied to b.txt)
      \                     /
       (hg copy a.txt b.txt)
```

> - If it turns out to do 'the wrong thing(tm)' for our case, how do I
>     unflag the file as beeing a copy of another file?

This mechanism only kicks in when you merge. If `b.txt` is not present in the
common ancestor revision (init in the above graph), then Mercurial will
do a search backwards to see if `b.txt` is copied from somewhere else.

Let us continue the above graph in abbreviated form:

```
(i) -- (edit a) -- (a edit copied to b) -- (edit a) -- (merge)
   \              /                                   /
    (copy a b) --/------- (edit b) ------------------/
```

The question is how the final merge is done. The common ancestor point
is now the `copy a b` node and here both `a` and `b` are present. This means
that there wont be any search for copies! So the second edit to `a` wont
be merged into `b`.

To double-check, I tried it out:

```
$ hg init
$ echo a > a
$ hg add a
$ hg commit -m init
$ hg copy a b
$ hg commit -m "copy a b"
```

This was the copy, `b` now contains `a` only.

```
$ hg update 0
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ echo aa >> a
$ hg commit -m "edit a"
created a new head
$ hg merge
merging a and b to b
0 files updated, 1 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
$ hg commit -m "a edit copied to b"
```

This was the first merge and the edit to `a` has been copied into `b`:

```
$ cat b
a
aa
```

We now make changes in parallel:

```
$ echo aaa >> a
$ hg commit -m "edit a again"
$ hg update 3
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ echo bbb >> b
$ hg commit -m "edit b"
created new head
$ hg merge
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
```

There are no further copying done:

```
$ cat a
a
aa
aaa
$ cat b
a
aa
bbb
```

As for disabling this... you can't really explicitly disable the copy
detection. But as I hope to have illustrated above, it wont "bother" you
again after the first merge.

If the first merge is a problem, then you can use `hg resolve --tool
internal:local` to reset the files back to their state before you
started the merge. So with

```
$ hg resolve --tool internal:local b
```

we could have brought `b` back to just containing one line with `a`.

Comment: Sorry, **can not** confirm copy-changes on merge heads in *my* test. `>hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.0.1)`

Comment: Also not in the first merge? Please write mercurial@selenic.com so that we can discuss it in full there, that's much better than these small comment boxes :)

Comment: "Also not in the first merge?" - yes. e-mail noted, message will be send (with logs)

Comment: It's strange if you cannot reproduce it with my steps... Thanks for sending the logs to the list, that should make it easier to discuss.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? I didn't see any logs on the mailing list.

Comment: I wanted to note: the effect is not to keep `a` and `b` "in synch" through the first merge.  In the 1st-merge, `b` and only `b` winds up the merged result of any changes to `a` on the b-free branch, along with the changes to `b` on the branch with the `b` copy.  (It wasn't clear to me reading the answer above whether hg would also merge changes back to `a`, since the example didn't modify `b` before the 1st-merge.  From a quick test, I believe it does not.)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I unflag the file as being a copy of another file?

If you revert a hg copy, the copied-to file remains in your working directory afterwards, untracked. You just have to add it normally.
The copied-from file isn't affected at all.

```
% hg copy file new-file
% hg status -C
A new-file
__file
% hg revert new-file
% hg add new-file
% hg status -C
A new-file
```

Reference: [Mercurial: The definitive guide](https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/undo.html#file-management-errors)