# Breaking Mercurial file "links"?

Tags: mercurial

We seem to have messed up some of our HG configuration.

When merging we see a few of these entries:

```
warning: detected divergent renames of core/src/main/java/x/y/z/MyFile.java to:
 core/src/main/java/x/y/z/NewFileA.java
 core/src/main/java/x/y/z/NewFileB.java
```

MyFile should not be linked to the "new files".   How can you break this link?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot break the link after the fact. The link was created when you (most likely) did

```
$ hg rename MyFile.java NewFileA.java
```

in one branch and someone did

```
$ hg rename MyFile.java NewFileB.java
```

in another. When merging the two branches, you will end up with both `NewFileA.java` and `NewFileB.java`. Some might consider that a conflict, hence the warning.

It's also possible that you did

```
$ hg copy MyFile.java NewFileA.java
$ hg copy MyFile.java NewFileB.java
```

and did so on purpose. In that case there's no conflict and the warning is unneeded. Mercurial cannot distinguish the two cases internally since `hg rename X Y` is the same as `hg copy X Y; hg remove X`. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531968/110204) for information about what `hg copy` really does.

So, don't worry, nothing is messed up. After you merge you wont see the warning again — the warning only appears if you merge with a branch where `MyFile.java` still exists.

Comment: Yes, I think we did do hg copy unintentionally - I think IntelliJ (with HG integration enabled) did this when I "copied" a file.  

If we change MyFile and then do a merge, will HG now try to merge the changes to "new files"?

I would have thought there was a way to break the link..  oh well.

Comment: It's only in the *first* merge between a branch where you still have `MyFile` and a branch were you have the copies that Mercurial will try to copy the `MyFile` changes into the two copies. After that you wont see anything special the "magic link" has been broken.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's some negative repercussion that I'm not aware of, you *can* break the link by doing a remove or forget of the inadvertent copy target file, committing that, and then re-adding the file (with the same content). Changes to the original copy source will not be merged to the re-added file.

In Mercurial 3.7.2 I have been able to reproduce *subsequent* merges (not just the first merge) applying changes to the copy target, which is counter to the documentation, although I have not dug into this further. Here I am referring to merges *to* the branch where the copy was committed, not the other direction.